# Como faço para um elemento não sobrepor outro?

Tags: css, div, layout-responsivo, html

É o seguinte. Eu tenho uma div, que no meu caso é o corpo da página, denteo desta div eu tenho duas bordas, a direita e a esquerda, e dentro da div eu também tenho um flexbox com algumas imagens. Ele fica certo, porém quando diminui o tamanho da página as imagens do flexbox ficam por cima da borda direita.

Comment: falta você colocar css e o HTML, e se puder uma captura de tela do resultado

Comment: Rafael sem o seu HTML e CSS não da para te responder, edite sua pergunta como o código que vc já tem

Answer (score 1):

Tudo explicado no código. (fonte: [https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/))

```css
.container {
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  /* Quebra a linha assim que um dos flex itens não puder mais ser compactado. */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  /* O flex: 1; é necessário para que cada item se expanda ocupando o tamanho máximo do container. */
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>flex-wrap: wrap;</h1>
<section class="container wrap">
  <div class="item">TesteDoItem1</div>
  <div class="item">TesteDoItem2</div>
  <div class="item">TesteDoItem3</div>
</section>
```